# Executing a command with command line parameters and writing the output to a text file

Tags: windows, command-line

Executing a command with command line parameters (on Windows 8.1 64bit) works fine

```
test.pbrt --ncores 1
```

or

```
test.pbrt [--ncores 1]
```

Executing a command and writing the output to a text file (on Windows 8.1 64bit) works fine

```
test.pbrt > test.txt
```

How can you combine both of them (without generating a separate bat file)? The following seems to ignore the command line argument and even stops outputting to the command line (only outputs to the text file).

```
test.pbrt --ncores 1 > test.txt
```

Edit: `.pbrt` is an ascii text file, the default program for opening those files is an executable file I created

Comment: Try "test.pbrt --ncores 1" >test.txt

Comment: @MarioWerner output: '"test.pbrt --ncores 1"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry, test.pbrt "--ncores 1" >test.txt should work. If not, what kind of file is "test.pbrt"?

Answer (score 2):

The ">" directs standard output to a file. So if command stops outputing to console is perfectly OK.
As about ignoring the parameters - it can be affected by script (what script is that - You didnn't specified)

Comment: True. I just read his post again. Completely missed that part. If you redirect the output to a file, there is no output to the console anymore. This is an expected behaviour.

Comment: This is not the case when executing test.pbrt > test.txt, the output is both written to the command line and to the text file.

Comment: @Matthias what if you use the full program name / path? "C:\Path\To Your \Program.exe" test.pbrt --ncores 1 >test.txt ?

Comment: @Matthias, check the file type command associated with .pbrt files: `for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %a in ('assoc .pbrt') do @ftype %a`. It should be something like `"Path\To\Program.exe" "%1" %*`.

Comment: @eryksun output: File association not found for extension .pbrt

Comment: @Matthias, probably you used Explorer to create the association, which doesn't set the association in the HKLM registry hive, but instead stores the association in its own key, and it typically doesn't set it up right to handle command-line arguments. From an elevated command prompt, create and associate the file type, e.g. `ftype pbrtfile="Path\To\Program.exe" "%1" %*` and then `assoc .pbrt=pbrtfile`. You'll probably need to select the new `pbrtfile` filetype association in Explorer as well.

Comment: @eryksun yes I used Explorer; executing the first one results in: File type 'pbrtfile' not found or no open command associated with it.

Comment: @Mathias, you need to use an elevated command prompt (i.e. run as administrator) to set the registry key.

Comment: @Matthias, here's a bit of background: Windows starts a new process via `CreateProcess`, but that requires a PE executable (typically .exe) or .bat/.cmd script. Executing other file types is handled by the shell32 function `ShellExecuteEx`, which calls `CreateProcess` with the associated `open` or `runas` (UAC) command found in the registry. The associations are defined in several places, for both the system and the current user. But the built-in `ftype` and `assoc` commands in the command prompt only work with keys set for the system (local machine) under `HKLM\Software\Classes`.

Comment: @eryksun it works, what does the meaning "%1" %* suffix?

Comment: @Matthias, `"%1"` is the path to the file, in quotes in case it contains spaces. `%*` is the rest of the command line arguments.

Comment: @Matthias, note that the command line is first processed by the cmd shell, such that `> test.txt` causes cmd to open/truncate the file "test.txt" and temporarily redirect  stdout to the file, which gets inherited by the child process. It doesn't include `> test.txt` in the command-line that it passes to `ShellExecuteEx`.